# How to call jQuery (with CoffeeScript) code in Ruby on Rails 3.x for better performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm developing a complex web application and now I'm at the point to refactor jQuery calls. I split my CoffeeScript code into separated files for different controller.

In every file I'm currently call

```
jQuery -> 
  $('.someClass').click ->
    # doSomething
```

Is it necessary to call the initializing function of jQuery in every file again?

Thanks
Lars

Comment: No. $('.someClass').click -> ... is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ sign is an alias for Jquery. So no, you don't need to initalize Jquery function.